# How to test next React Components with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

Given an app like:

```
<TestEnvSetup>
    <App />   
</TestEnvSetup>
```

and app.js

```
<UserForm>
   <DatePicker />
   <AutocompleteField />
   <MoreFields />
</UserForm>
```

I know I need to `mount(<TestEnvSetup><App /></TestEnvSetup>)`, but how would I go about traversing components to compare state, interactions ect? For example make sure that the AutocompleteField signaled some flag on the App's state. Or am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: I think doing such a deep traversal(`integration test`) is quite painful with Enzyme, It would be better to shallow render the component and test it's functionality. 

If you must, you can always do some deep querying (`wrapper.find('.inputField')). 

regarding internal states for the internal components, unless you store a ref for them in the container, I'm not sure they're easily accessible